# Чтение данных отправляемых на IP адрес

Tags: сервер, ip

Появился вопрос. 
Нам собираются слать данные с GPS устройств. 
в тех документации написано, что нужно указать IP адрес сервера, а так же порт.

Отсюда вопросы 
Как указать порт на сервере? 
Как получать эти данные и обрабатывать их?

Comment: Этот вопрос нужно задать тем, кто собрался данные слать. Вариантов, как это сделать очень очень много.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения данных на сервере нужно установить на нем веб сервер, который будет слушать определенный порт.
Посмотрите в сторону Apache, Nginx.
Как язык для обработки входящих данных может подойти php либо (лучше) python

Comment: Почему именно "веб сервер"? Автор не указал что за устройства будут это делать. Например, есть программно-аппаратное решение "АвтоГРАФ" у которого есть своё серверное приложение принимающее инфу от GPS устройств. Довелось как-то админить "это" под freebsd :'(

Comment: @nobody В любом случае это скорее всего будет tcp, если есть приложение которое может решить данную задачу - конечно лучше использовать его, но в вопросе говорится конкретно о том, как получить данные которые будут приходить на ip, поэтому.. и говорю что на сервере сначала нужно поднять тот же веб сервер, который будет их принимать. А вообще постановка вопроса очень не конкретная, автор ещё очень далек от реализации

Comment: даже не факт, что там будет tcp, там вполне может быть udp. А может вообще что то свое.